# Controller is defined, but can not be found

Tags: ember.js

When trying to get the `nodeEditController` from `nodeController:startEditing`, I get the following problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
```

This is the `NodeController`:

```
SettingsApp.NodeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,

    startEditing: function () {
        debugger;
        var nodeEditController = this.get('controllers.nodeEdit');
        nodeEditController.set('content', this.get('content'));
        nodeEditController.startEditing();
        this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    ...
```

This is the `NodeEditController`:

```
SettingsApp.NodeEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['node'],

    startEditing: function () {
        //debugger;
        // add the contact and its associated phone numbers to a local transaction
        var node = this.get('content');
        var transaction = node.get('store').transaction();
        transaction.add(node);
        // contact.get('phones').forEach(function (phone) {
        //   transaction.add(phone);
        // });
        this.transaction = transaction;
    },
    ...
```

The error happens in line:

```
nodeEditController.set('content', this.get('content'));
```

Because:

```
var nodeEditController = this.get('controllers.nodeEdit');
```

Returns `undefined`. Why is that? The `NodeEditController` is defined!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NodeController is missing the `needs` property:

```
SettingsApp.NodeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs : ["nodeEdit"],
    isEditing: false,

    startEditing: function () {
        debugger;
        var nodeEditController = this.get('controllers.nodeEdit');
        nodeEditController.set('content', this.get('content'));
        nodeEditController.startEditing();
        this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    ...
```